# Uniqueness of approximations like the Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, approximation, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f: \mathbb {R} ^n \to \mathbb {R} $, I am curious about the uniqueness of a $k$th-order approximation at $c \in \mathbb {R}^n $,  i.e. a function $\phi(x)$ such that

$$ \frac {f(c + h) - \phi(c + h)} {\| h \|^k } \overset{h\to 0} { \to } 0,$$

and I want to show that there is a unique such $\phi$ that is a polynomial of degree $\leq k$ in $(x_1 - c_1, \dotsc , x_n - c_n) = (h_1 , \dotsc, h_n)$ (supposing that one exists at all). Of course, this will be the Taylor expansion of order $k$ at $c$. We can prove the uniqueness of the first order as follows: if $p_1$, $p_1'$ are polynomials of degree $\leq 1$ in the components, then they are of the form $$p_1 = v + \langle  w, h \rangle \\ p_1' = v' + \langle  w', h \rangle,$$

so since $\frac {f- p_1} {\|h\|}$ and $ \frac {f - p_2} { \| h \| } \to 0$ as $h\to 0$, we have that

$$ \frac { p_2 - p_1 } { \| h \| } = \frac {v-v'} { \| h \| }  +\frac { \langle w-w' , h \rangle } { \|h\| }, $$

and if we let $h \to 0$ parallel to $w-w'$, we see that this can go to zero iff $v = v', w = w'$.

If we try to do the same thing in second order, we'll end up with

$$ \frac {v - v'} {\| h \|^2 } + \frac { \langle w - w', h \rangle} {\|  h\|^2} + \frac {h^T (H - H')h} {\|h \|^2} $$ goes to zero, and we'd like to conclude from this that $H = H'$ etc. I'm not exactly sure how we'd do this; we'd maybe like to use the matrix norm, but that gives an upper bound, and we need a lower bound (something to force to zero).

Anyway, my questions are:

1. How can we show the uniqueness of such a $k$th order approximation in general?
2. Given a $k$th order approximation which is also a polynomial of degree $\leq k$ in the $h_i$, how can we show that those terms which are of degree $\leq k-1$ form a $k-1$th-order approximation?

It would be a bonus if we can answer questions 1 and 2 without reference to the derivative, and then afterward we can of course show that the existence of such an approximation is equivalent to $k$-times differentiability at $c$ (sometimes it is even taken as the definition).

**Edit:** @40votes has pointed out that we cannot reason from the existence of such an approximation to the existence of a derivative of order higher than 1.

Comment: You can't get derivatives above 1st order from any kind of polynomial approximation. Consider $f(x)=x^{10}\sin(x^{-20})$, etc.

Comment: @40votes: Are you quite sure?

Comment: @40votes We may be talking about different things...I mean for instance a polynomial $p(h) = ah + b$ such that $(f(c + h) - p(h))/h = 0$. Certainly that quickly implies the existence of the derivative. Notice the polynomial is not in $x$.

Comment: @EricAuld: You seem to be postulating existence and then deducing uniqueness? Existence is equivalent to $k$ times differentiability. Terms higher than degree $2$ will be homogeneous polynomials which correspond to higher-order tensors, not matrices.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, supposing one exists, I would like to show it is unique, and that if we take only the terms of degree $\leq k-1$, those will be a $k-1$th-order approximation. I agree they will be tensors, not matrices.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried to clarify the question a little bit.

Comment: @TedShifrin The function $x^{10}\sin(x^{-20})$ admits a polynomial approximation of order $k=9$ at every point. It is not twice differentiable.

Comment: Eric, I would suggest you think a little bit about the single-variable argument. The same argument should work. You want to prove the lemma that if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$ that goes to $0$ faster than $\|h\|^k$, then $P=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, that clarifies things a bit. It seems we can switch to $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates and get $r^k/r^k$ times some sines and cosines.  I will keep trying! Any suggestions for question #2?

Comment: @40votes: You're right, of course. Eric, the correct reasoning is that *if* $f$ is $k$ times diff'able at $c$ and $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\le k$ that agrees with $f$ to order $k$ at $c$, *then* $P$ is the $k$th order Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @40votes What is the approximation? Where can I read more about this counter-example?

Comment: @EricAuld The zero polynomial approximates that function at $0$, and at other points you have the usual Taylor approximation. It's a variation of the standard $x^2\sin(1/x)$ function discussed in real analysis textbooks.

Comment: Eric, (2) should be a $1$-line argument. Think of $f(x)=P(x) + o(x^k)$.

Comment: @40votes I see...is such a polynomial approximation still unique, although it does not imply differentiability of order $> 1$?

Comment: @EricAuld Uniqueness holds, and is a consequence of the fact that two polynomials of degree at most  $k$ whose difference is $o(|x-c|^k)$ are identically equal. Just expand them about $c$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I get what you mean...$o(x^{k-1}) + o(x^k) = o(x^{k-1})$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can we show the uniqueness of such a $k$th order approximation in general?

If two polynomials $p,q$ of degree at most $k$ satisfy 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{p(c+h)-q(c+h)}{\|h\|^k}=0\tag1$$ for some $c$, then $p\equiv q$. Indeed, the difference $p-q$, being a polynomial of degree at most $k$, admits a finite Taylor expansion
$$p(c+h)-q(c+h) = \sum_{|j|\le k} c_j h^j\tag2$$
where $j$ is a multiindex. Using (1) repeatedly with $k$ replaced by $0,1,2,\dots,k$ we find that $c_j=0$ for all $j$.

> Given a $k$th order approximation which is also a polynomial of degree $\le k$, how can we show that those terms which are of degree $\le k−1$ form a $(k−1)$th-order approximation?

Given $p(c+h)=f(c+h)+o(\|h\|^k)$, write $p=q+p_k$ where $p_k$ contains the monomials in $h$ that are of degree precisely $k$, and $q$ has degree $<k$. Note that $p_{k}(c+h)=O(\|h\|^k)$ which is $o(\|h\|^{k-1})$. Hence 
$$p(c+h)-p_{k}(h)=f(c+h)+o(\|h\|^{k-1})$$

---

The existence of $k$th order approximation, for any $k\ge 1$, implies first-order differentiability. However, it does not imply the existence of second or higher order derivatives. A standard counterexample is $f(x)=x^{k+1}\sin x^{-k-1}$. The problem is that a bound on $f$ gives no control over the oscillation of $f'$. A more extreme example of this kind is 
$$f(x)=\exp (-x^{-2} ) \chi_{\mathbb Q}$$
which is discontinuous everywhere except $0$ but has polynomial approximation of all orders at $0$. (In both examples above, the function is extended to $x=0$ by $0$.)

In convex analysis and some areas of PDE one encounters  *pointwise second-order derivative*, e.g., [Second order differentiability of convex functions in Banach spaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1994-342-01/S0002-9947-1994-1145959-4/) by Borwein and Noll. These precisely correspond to the existence of 2nd order approximation described in the question. One can similarly define the *pointwise $k$th derivative* of $f$ as the corresponding derivative of its $k$th order polynomial approximation. I haven't seen this used for $k\ge 3$, although the concept is natural.

A related concept is [jet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Is it easy to prove that $p_k(x+h) = O(\|h\|^k)$? I thought $$\frac {x_1^{\alpha_1} \dotsb x_n^{\alpha_n} } {\|x\|^p}$$ had no limit at zero if $\sum \alpha_i = p$. Does it have an upper bound?

Comment: @Eric It does not have a limit, but it does have an upper bound. First, restrict to the unit sphere and use compactness+continuity. Second, note that multiplying $x$ by a nonzero scalar does not change this quotient.

Comment: Below eq. (2) you say: "Using (1) repeatedly with k replaced by 0,1,2,…,k we find that cj=0 for all j." How do you conclude this? See my question about it: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2148735.