# How to prove that if $p(x)/||x||^k\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, for a multivariable polynomial $p$ of degree $k$, then $p=0$.

Tags: analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452192) the following claim is made for a $k$-th order multivariate polynomial $p:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, i.e., $p(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} c_\alpha x^\alpha$ in multi-index notation (see remark B below).

**Claim: If $$\frac{p(x)}{||x||^k}\to 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad x\to 0 \tag{1}$$ then $p=0$.**

I'm trying to prove this, but I'm not gettig anywhere. The answer mentioned above justifies the claim by saying

> Using (1) repeatedly with $k$ replaced by $0,1,2,…,k$ we find that $c_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha$.

So let's see. Taking $k=0$ in (1) yields $\frac{p(x)}{||x||}\to 0 $, or,

$$ \sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} c_\alpha \frac{x^\alpha}{||x||} \to 0 $$

The argument now should probably be that for $|\alpha|>1$ we have $\frac{x^\alpha}{||x||} \to 0$ (but I truly don't see how this follows), so that we are left with

$$ \sum_{|\alpha| =1} c_\alpha \frac{x^\alpha}{||x||} \to 0 $$

which should in turn imply (but again I don't see why) that $c_\alpha=0$ for each $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$. Now we can consider (1) with $k=2$, do something similar, and continue in this fashion until we have shown that $c_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha$.

*I'm really stuck so I would appreciate any help! The reason that I want to prove this claim is that I want to prove uniqueness of the polynomial explansion of a $k$ times differentiable multivariable function.*

**Some remarks:** A) The mentioned answer did not specify what norm $||x||$ is used, but I guess this makes no difference since all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent. So we could e.g. take $||x||^2 = ||x_1||^2+ ||x_2||^2 + \dots + ||x_n||^2$ for concreteness.

B) In the multi-index notation, $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ and $x^\alpha\equiv x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ and $|\alpha| \equiv |\alpha_1|+ |\alpha_2| + \dots + |\alpha_n|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Hopefully this is clear when $n=1.$ For $n>1,$ use the homogenous expansion $p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k}p_j(x),$ where $p_j$ is homogeneous of degree $j.$ Now think of $x=r\zeta,$ where $r=|x|$ and $\zeta \in S,$ the unit sphere. We then have

$$p(x) = p(r\zeta) = \sum_{j=0}^{k}r^jp_j(\zeta).$$

On each ray $\{r\zeta : r\ge 0\},$ we are in one variable.

Comment: Ah yes this works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually typing this proof out for myself, so I thought why not share it here.

We want to prove the following claim.

*If $p(x)$ is any $k^\text{th}$ order polynomial in $n$ variables $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ for which
$$\frac{p(x)}{||x||^k}\to 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad x\to 0 \tag{1},$$
then it follows that $p=0$. Here $||x||$ represents the Euclidean norm.*

*Proof.* We write $p(x) = a + a_ix^i + a_{ij} x^i x^j + \dots + a_{i_1\dots i_k}x^{i_1}\dots x^{i_k}$ (using the Einstein summation convention, i.e. summing over all repeated indices). From condition (1), it follows immedately that in fact

$$\frac{p(x)}{||x||^m}\to 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad x\to 0 \tag{2}$$

for all $m\leq k$. We start with $m=0$. This implies that $a = 0$. Next we repeatedly apply condition (2) with $m = 1,2,\dots, k$. We claim that the $m$-th step implies that $a_{i_1\dots i_m}x^{i_1}\dots x^{i_m} = 0$, and we will prove this by induction on $m$. For $m=0$ we have already proven the statement, and our induction hypothesis is that $a_{i_1\dots i_q}x^{i_1}\dots x^{i_q} = 0$ for all $q<m$. Before employing condition (2), note that any $p$-th order homogeneous polynomial $\tilde p(x)$ satisfies

$$\frac{\tilde p(x)}{||x||^q}\to 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad x\to 0$$

for all $q<p$ (this is easily seen by just noticing that $|x^i|<||x||$). Hence in the expression for $p(x)/||x||^m$, the terms of order larger than $m$ vanish in the limit. Similary, the terms of order lower than $m$ vanish, by the induction hypothesis. So only the $m$-th order terms remain and condition (2) reduces to

$$\frac{a_{i_1\dots i_ m}x^{i_1}\dots x^{i_m}}{||x||^m}\to 0\qquad\text{as}\qquad x\to 0.\tag{3}$$

At this point we can use *zhw.*'s answer: we evaluate the limit radially inwards, i.e., we write $x = r\xi$, where $\xi^i$ is a constant point on the unit sphere and we take $r\to 0$. The limit (3) then reduces to $a_{i_1\dots i_ m}\xi^{i_1}\dots \xi^{i_m}\to 0$ as $r\to 0$. Since this does not depend on $r$, it says simply that $a_{i_1\dots i_ m}\xi^{i_1}\dots \xi^{i_m}=0$. This must hold for all $\xi$ on the unit sphere. But then, multiplying by $r$ again, it follows that also $a_{i_1\dots i_ m}x^{i_1}\dots x^{i_m}=0$. This proves the induction step. And this completes the proof.